# Xbox One-Xbox 360 connection via hdmi not working

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, hdmi

I hooked up my 360 to the One via HDMI cord. When I select "TV" I do see the 360 homescreen, but out of proportion. When I move the stick to select my account, the Xbox one displays the play/pause/fast forward menu whenever I move the stick as if I was watching a youtube video and I can't use the 360 at all. I'm pretty sure that I set up my two Xbox's correctly. What is going on?

Comment: @TimmyJim is correct, you just access the TV app with your Xbox One controller. You navigate everything else within the TV app, which is displaying your Xbox 360, using the old 360 controller.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the intended way it's suppose to work. The Xbox One input HDMI doesn't allow you to use your Xbox One controller with the Xbox 360 (it doesn't make sense for it to work that way). You will likely still have to use the 360 controller, since the 360 console can only detect the signals produced by the 360 controller. You can still use some of the Xbox One features, but you'll probably have to use the Xbox One controller to navigate them.

Connecting you Xbox 360 up to your Xbox One like this allows you to play Xbox 360 game while still being able to reap the benefit of the Xbox One features. You will just have to switch between controllers to do so.

As for the out of proportion screen, try [this](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/console/adjust-display-settings)

> 1. Scroll left on the Home screen to open the guide.
> 2. Select Settings.
> 3. Select All Settings.
> 4. Select Display & sound, and then select Video output.
> 5. Choose the display and picture settings appropriate for your TV.

There should be an option called calibrate HDTV, which may be able to help solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I was using older HDMI cable and as soon as I switched from 480p to 1080p I only received a black screen. I couldn’t figure out what was wrong or get to settings again.  I switched to a Ethernet fast HDMI cable and all worked fine.

1. Turn both devices off.
2. Plug in TV HDMI. Then Xbox 360.
3. Turn on TV then Xbox 360.
4. Go to settings on Xbox and change to 1080p.
5. Put in disc and away you go.